# Solution of Integral

Tags: definite-integrals

I want to solve the following integral

$$ \frac{\alpha \beta}{2} \int_0^\pi \cos\theta \sec^{2}\theta(\tan(\theta/2))^{-\beta-1} (1+\gamma(\tan(\theta/2))^{-\beta})^{-\frac{\alpha}{\gamma}-1}d\theta$$
after subtituting $(\tan(\theta/2))^{-\beta}=z$

I got this
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{{(1+\gamma z)}{}^{-(\frac{\alpha}{\gamma}+1)}}{1+z^{-\frac{2}{\beta}}}dz$$

where $\alpha, \beta and \gamma>0.$ 
How to solve above integral? Kindly help me in this regards.

Comment: You want that, but what is your question?

Comment: @Did I simply need someone help me to solve the stated integral.

Comment: What have you already tried? What have you already thought of?

Comment: @Pedro Nice to know. Why?

Comment: @Did since it was pretty obvious what the question was, namely: how can i solve this integral? However, I find that the person could give more information about what he/she has already tried and the methods the persons already thought of, in order to help him or her optimally.

Comment: @Pedro thanks for comments, I initially start with larger problem, but stuck on that stage. No hint is working.

Comment: @Pedro There is, in effect, no question here. If there was, perhaps the OP would have added anything personal to their post and this would have produced an acceptable one. (But you know all this, don't you?)

Comment: Have you thought already of some methods? What have you tried to do? People expect that you have shown some effort or that you can present a list of things you might think can help to solve the problem, but you don't know how to implement it. Where did you found the problem? Is it from a book? Is it something you made up yourself? So that people know whether there actually should be a solution and that it is actually solvable. If you don't put this information in your post, your question might be downvoted by people.

Answer (score 0):

For $B\in\mathbb N$ we have $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{(1+Ax)^B}{1+x^C}~dx~=~\frac\pi C\cdot\sum_{k=0}^B~{B\choose k}~\frac{A^k}{\sin\bigg((k+1)~\dfrac\pi C\bigg)}~,~$ which

can be easily shown by expanding the numerator using the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) and letting

$t=\dfrac1{1+x^C}~,~$ then recognizing the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral,

and employing Euler's [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) to simplify the result.

Comment: But the RHS diverges for every integer C?

Comment: @Did: For convergence we must have $C>B+1$, obviously, so $\dfrac{k+1}C$ will always be strictly in between $0$ and $1$, thus avoiding the problematic points $\sin0=\sin\pi=0.$

Comment: This should be mentioned clearly in any answer.

Comment: @Did: And why is that ? To prevent the reader from God-forbid ever developing any critical thought and analytic skills ?

Comment: Pfff... $ $ $ $

Comment: @Lucian For $B=-(\frac{\alpha}{\gamma}+1)$ this solution does not work.

Comment: @Azeem: Your initial post did not mention anything about the parameters in question being positive.